# Manjaro not connecting to some websites

Tags: networking, manjaro

I have an issue where some network requests return `ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE` and others resolve successfully.
Success and failure depends on the domain, for example requests to amazon.com resolve while github.com fails.

I can solve the issue until the next reboot by running `sudo dhcpcd wlp1s0`, where wlp1s0 is my wifi network.

My System:

`uname -a Linux archangel 5.1.8-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Jun 9 20:44:14 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: - Not an answer -
you can try asking/looking in the manjaro forum at https://forum.manjaro.org/
p.s. sorry to disappoint that i don't have an answer but you might have better luck in the manjaro specific forum

Comment: Maybe Connectivy issues influencing the DNS cache or having a wrong /rogue dns server setup. Unfortunately the question is too broad.